# ¿Como puedo obtener la fecha o periodo de fecha pasando el numero de semana?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

Si desde SQL tengo el numero de la semana "1" como puedo obtener la fecha o el rango de fechas de esa semana. Se que para obtener el numero de la semana se hace con "DATEPART" ¿Existe algún modo de invertir la operación para que me proporcione la fecha usando el numero de semana?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tienes un número de semana entonces deberías tener una fecha o año de origen, en cuyo caso simplemente deberías sumar la semana a la fecha de origen, por ejemplo si tu origen es el año 2022, podrías hacer algo así:

```
declare @NroSemana INT = 2

select dateadd(wk, @NroSemana -1, '2022-01-01' )
```

Comment: Si me funciono de la siguiente manera SELECT DATEADD(day, -5, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEPART(WK,A.Vencimiento)-1, '01.01.2022' )) AS DIA_INICIO_SEMANA,DATEADD(day, 1, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEPART(WK,A.Vencimiento)-1, '01.01.2022' )) AS DIA_FIN_SEMANA